# syntax error in calling custom function inside another trigger function

Tags: postgresql

continuing to earlier post:

my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION .instrbals(
    str text,
    sub text,
    startpos integer DEFAULT 1,
    occurrence integer DEFAULT 1)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
declare 
    tail text;
    shift int;
    pos int;
    i int;
begin
    shift:= 0;
    if startpos = 0 or occurrence <= 0 then
        return 0;
    end if;
    if startpos < 0 then
        str:= reverse(str);
        sub:= reverse(sub);
        pos:= -startpos;
    else
        pos:= startpos;
    end if;
    for i in 1..occurrence loop
        shift:= shift+ pos;
        tail:= substr(str, shift);
        pos:= strpos(tail, sub);
        if pos = 0 then
            return 0;
        end if;
    end loop;
    if startpos > 0 then
        return pos+ shift- 1;
    else
        return length(str)- pos- shift+ 1;
    end if;
end $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

My select statement and error:

```
select instrbals(;&
217011802;217011802;;
885;;F;F;10/01/2017 13:46:17;5.5100;;mmol/L;;0;;;;,;,1,2+1)

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: select instrbals(;&
                         ^
```

Comment: Looking at your question gives me headache! - Would you mind using formatting for your questions to make them readable?

Comment: you have to use quotes around text field, I don't see any quote in your query.

Comment: String constants in SQL need to be enclosed in single quotes `'` not this strange `;&` thingy: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS